# React Redux Typescript in 2020 is confusing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, ecmascript-6

I've just started learning React, Redux, Typescript and ES6. And its been frustrating cause so many tutorials do things differently without really explaining that it could be done another way (which another tutorial does). The bigger problem is that so many updates seems to have happens after these tutorials are made that I do not know which I should be using.

Can someone please make a summary of what the LATEST thing I should be using in React and Redux. And maybe how to tie typescript with that?

I'm mostly confused with redux. I've tried redux alone, react-redux tutorials, redux thunk, and their typescript tools. Again, each of them do it differently, so it just confuses me on what is being replaced by what. If anyone can even lead me to an actual complete tutorial that would be great.

I understand this is vague. So I apologize. I'm just really lost, cause I still can't grasp most of the many knowledge i read through tutorials.

Comment: Redux is probably overkill for most small projects, so you could also consider leaving that part out of your stack for a little longer.

Comment: Technology moves fast, and unfortunately this out-of-date problem will not go away because of it. Ironically it will have the same effect on this question and answers as new things come out and "latest" becomes old.

Comment: I recommend using Redux with React Hooks as outlined in this course I created: https://egghead.io/courses/redux-with-react-hooks-8a37

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the [official redux tutorials from the redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index). They will familiarize you with Redux Toolkit, which is the recommended approach to writing Redux nowadays. Redux toolkit is tightly integrated with TypeScript and you won't need to write many types by hand - also almost all examples in [the redux toolkit API docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) are available in TypeScript and showcase how *little* types you actually have to write.
The tutrials will also briefly touch `useSelector` and `useDispatch`, which again need almost no typings apart from some setup. Best would be to just start with [the official redux-typescript template for create-react-app](https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux-typescript) which has all that setup already and contains some examples.

You should not need to use `connect` in a modern React application with hooks - and that is probably for the better, as `connect` can be a bit more work to use with TypeScript. If you should need it though, [please follow this approach](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically)

Comment: Warning for the react-redux documentation, it is a bit out of date and still uses connect in the examples.

Comment: Which is why I didn't link it ;)